# scrapy scraping url from between tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a quick question regarding scrapy. From what I can tell Link extractors only grab links that have an attribute like href=. The only thing I am having trouble with is grabbing links that are like this: `<link> link here </link>`Here is one of the current rules that I am using for my crawl spider: `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('feedproxy'), tags='link'), follow=True, callback="parse_urls")` Any help would be appreciated, thanks. -Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to process these kind of links manually. `Link Extractors` can be controlled via [`tags` and `attrs` arguments](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml):

> tags (str or list) – a tag or a list of tags to consider when
>   extracting links. Defaults to ('a', 'area').
>
> attrs (list) – an
>   attribute or list of attributes which should be considered when
>   looking for links to extract (only for those tags specified in the
>   tags parameter). Defaults to ('href',)

But, they can get links from attributes only.

So, in your current configuration, you can expect only the following types of links to be extracted:

```
<link href="http://google.com">test</link>
```

Comment: ya i figured that is what was being extracted I'm just wondering how to manually exctract the links.

Comment: @samuelm33 just do it in the `parse()` callback using `response.xpath('//link/text()')`. Iterate over the results and return/yield [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) instances if needed to follow the links.